# Increase json ordered list by 1 using python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file that is similar to this

```
    {
        "items":[
            {
                "item":0
            },
            {
                "item":1
            },
            {
                "item":2
            },
            {
                "item":3
            }
        ]
    }
```

I'd like to increase each number behind item by 1 and keeping the same format. The output should be

```
    {
        "items":[
            {
                "item":1
            },
            {
                "item":2
            },
            {
                "item":3
            },
            {
                "item":4
            }
        ]
    }
```

How can I do it using Python?

Thanks.

Comment: start with `import json`. Seriously what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import json
>>> data = ''' {
...         "items":[
...             {
...                 "item":0
...             },
...             {
...                 "item":1
...             },
...             {
...                 "item":2
...             },
...             {
...                 "item":3
...             }
...         ]
...     }'''
>>> print(json.dumps({a:[{b:1+c[b]for b in c}for c in d]for a,d in json.loads(data).items()},indent=4))
{
    "items": [
        {
            "item": 1
        },
        {
            "item": 2
        },
        {
            "item": 3
        },
        {
            "item": 4
        }
    ]
}
```